# How to get rid of need of trailing slash in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am having problems of trailing slash in my spring mvc project.I am using Spring 4.2.0.release .My problem is that if I  provide link in my view page like  href="link",and in controller: `@RequestMapping(value="/link",method=RequestMethod.GET)`,then on clicking link `localhost:8080/project/link` automatically goes to `localhost:8080` and link does not work.

I tried a lot and figured out a simple solution  `href="link/"`. This works. But for redirection and other frequent processes,I feel not good.
How can I solve it ?I want to redirect with `href="link"` not `href="link/"`.

My MVC configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.subash.shub")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }


}
```

And WebAppInitializer is :

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your complete Controller code here?

Comment: I have just test controller:
@Controller
public class NavigationController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/link", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String goHome() {
  return "test";
 }

}